# Hubble constant: a constant or might be a function?

Tags: cosmology, observable-universe

When I read  or watch youtube videos about Hubble constant everybody agree it is no more considered as a constant but why nobody talk about acceleration difference between closer and distant objects considering that the further ones add a more hugher space inflation factor but on the other hand they were faster in the far past than the closer object are approximately nowdays both due to dark energy?

Answer (score 3):

I think it is a common misconception. Hubble constant is only a constant a fixed time (of course). In fact the whole point of Friedmann equation is to find the evolution of Hubble "constant".

Answer (score 3):

What is referred to as the "Hubble constant", $H_0$, is in fact the value of the Hubble parameter *now*.

The Hubble parameter, defined as $\dot{a}/a$ where $a(t)$ is the scale factor, varies with cosmic epoch. It was larger in the past and it seems to be decreasing now.

Comment: could you help me https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/665094/is-hubble-graph-straight-line-or-curve